# create <div> with steady size, but with scrollable text

Tags: html, css

I have already searched in the forum, but I wasn't able to find a solution for my problem. I would like to create two "div" which have steady height and internal scrolling. But when I add some text inside one of them, the height increase with it. What I want is that the "body" remains steal and just the content inside the "div" be scrollable, I would like that the final outcome is like the one in the image below, but it should be also responsive
[image]

Actually my html is:

```
 <div id="bodyapp"  class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 no-float">
            <div class="box content">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md no-float">
            <div class="box">Navigation</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ad my css is:

```
#bodyapp
 {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 80%;
 }

#bodyapp .row
 {
    height: 80%;
 }

#bodyapp .row .no-float
 {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    background-color: darkgray;
    margin:7px;
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Set height and overflow. Usually overflow: auto is preferred, unless you want a greyed out scrollbar, then overflow: scroll.  If you want to specify different values for vertical and horizontal scrollbars, use overflow-x and overflow-y

Comment: i have already tried to add at the .content class the property of height and overflow but nothing has changed. The nearest thing to the solution has been also adding to the .row class the overflow property. In this case however the site isn't working on the sm screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8u6032eq/1/

Basically you want to set an explicit height onto the < div > that has the text (in this case `.box`)

You should also add this to the following CSS declaration:

```
#bodyapp .row .no-float {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This problem was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the overflow property of css and also put the fix height and try to solve